# Returning values from lambdas expressions?

Tags: java, foreach, lambda, java-8

Basically what I have going on is I'm working on an interface system for Java, and my interfaces are made up of components. Please keep in mind that I'm using OpenGL, so the standard listeners are not available.

Basically what I need to do is find out if one of the interface's "click" boolean returns true, here's the code that I had written (Hoping for success)

```
if(Interface.interfaces.forEach((k, v)->v._clicked())) {
}
```

However, this isn't allowed. All of my interfaces are abstract, and stored in an `HashMap<>`.

Basically what I'm trying to do is the following:

```
if(!Interface.interfaces.forEach((k, v)->v._clicked())) {
    // Handle game related code
}
```

where the `_clicked()` method (which calls the abstract void `clicked()` after doing some logic) will handle the interface related code, so there's not any need for an else statement. The overall concept of this is to make it so clicking on a chatbox, etc won't make my player interact with the game world.

I have tons of interfaces, so iterating through them in a nice, neat manner would be nice.

If I cannot use lambda here, that's quite unfortunate, I know I can do it with a for/each Entry<> but I wanted to avoid it due to the sheer ugliness.

Comment: Sorry, but without more code I have no idea what to do with this.  What does `forEach` look like?  Without knowing what its parameter list looks like, or the types of `k` and `v`, or what the `_clicked` method looks like, I don't have any idea why this isn't allowed or what would help.

Comment: Apparently the two answerers have read your mind and figured out what the type of `Interface.interfaces` is.  Unfortunately they seem to have come up with two different ideas.  You could help us out by telling us, so that we don't have to try to read your mind.

Comment: @ajb - Obviously, _clicked() would be a boolean, as it's wrapped in an unconditional if() statement, I already stated that Interface.interfaces was a `HashMap<>` in the question.

Comment: Actually, you didn't state that `interfaces` was a `HashMap<>`; all you said was "All of my interfaces are abstract, and stored in an `HashMap<>`", which doesn't really say anything at all about the `interfaces` **identifier**.  You may think it's obvious, but it really isn't.  If you need us to know that `interfaces` is a `HashMap`, please say so explicitly or show us code.  Also if it's a `HashMap`, two of the answers (one deleted) suggest calling its `stream()` method which doesn't exist for a `HashMap`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As suggested, if you only need to determine if any of the interfaces return true from `*clicked()* then use:

```
Interface.interfaces.values().stream().anyMatch(Interface::_clicked))
```

Be aware though that this can short-circuit, if one of the `_clicked()` calls return true then the others may not be evaluated.  If the clicked call has side effects this may not be what you want.

To ensure all clicked calls are evaluated, you can instead use:

```
Interface.interfaces.stream().map(Interface::_clicked).reduce(false, (a, b) -> a || b);
```

Answer (score 3):

I think what you want is:

```
if (Interface.interfaces.values().stream().anyMatch(Interface::_clicked)) {
    // ...
}
```

Or:

```
if (Interface.interfaces.values().stream().noneMatch(Interface::_clicked)) {
    // ...
}
```